# Do I need to replace my swinging arm bushings?

Tags: suspension

I've removed the steering knuckles from my Audi Q3. When I move the swinging arm by hand it makes a creaking noise. Do the bushing(s) need to be replaced?

See video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hucz4sH1u4M

Comment: Not necessarily, spray some rubber lube on them and cycle the arm to work it in. This is what I have used for years but there are similar products....https://agscompany.com/product/ru-glyde-tire-mounting-and-rubber-lubricant-bottle-1-gal/

Comment: @Moab Thanks for the info. I'll get some rubber lube and when time permits inspect the bushes closer.